# MATLAB audioread - Problem calling one .wav file from struct in a cell

Tags: matlab, struct, syntax, wav

[image]

**`data_structure` is a cell of (length(num_sounds) row x 3 column cell**

- each row corresponds to a different sound
- first column = directory name
- second column = files struct for .wav files
- third column = formant data

  `for i=1:num_sounds;`
               `cd(char(sound_dirs{i})); %open a directory
              wav_list=dir('*.wav'); %get all the .wav files in the folder
              data_structure{i,2}=wav_list; % fills second column with struct the length of the .wav files. 
              data_structure{i,1}=words{i};
          end`

**problem lies here**

```
 for i=1:num_sounds;
        num_wavs=length(data_structure{i,2}); 
        for i=1:num_wavs;
            [y Fs]= audioread((data_structure{i,2}.name)); %%problem here
```

**I realize the issue is that I'm calling all the '.wav' files in the same folder at the same time and not taking each one at a time**

I tried `data_structure{1,2}.name(40); % the first folder has 47 .wav files`

but that didn't work.

`name` <-- holds all the the names of the .wav files.

[image]

Comment: `data_structure{1,2}(40).name`

Comment: **I tried this**                                                                                                   
     ````for i=1:num_sounds;
     i_num_wavs=length(data_structure{i,2});
     for j=1:i_num_wavs;
     [y Fs]= audioread(data_structure{i,2}(j).name);
     end
end````                                                                                                                                                                 I used @CrisLuengo's suggestion, and it worked in the command window but it still won't run in the script.

Comment: **error**                                                                                                            
````Error using audioread (line 90)
The filename specified was not found in the MATLAB path.````

````Error in celldir (line 37)
     [y Fs]= audioread(data_structure{i,2}(j).name);````

Comment: For some reason, the code I wrote, always opens up to the Tea_Pot directory, which is the last directory, regardless of what directory I have open in the beginning of  running the code. And then it stops, because the i=1 term, should correspond to Ball.  (have directories in alphabetical order) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55678142/matlab-specified-all-paths-but-its-always-opening-to-the-last-path

Comment: Don’t use `cd`. You end up in the last directory, so all the files you read are from there. Use `fullfile(directory_name,file_name)` both when listing the directory contents (where `file_name` is `*.wav`) and when reading the file.

Comment: A little confused, I used `cd` to open the directory to access the `.wav` files. And `fullfile` is used to create a path to the file.

Comment: Yes, you should do `dir('path/*.wav')` instead of `cd path; dir('*.wav')`. Always use explicit path names everywhere, never count on what the current directory is. You get fewer bugs that way.

Comment: I started writing an answer to your new question, but that's been deleted. Is this clear now? I'm suggesting `wav_list=dir(fullfile(char(sound_dirs{i}),'*.wav'));` and `audioread(fullfile(char(sound_dirs{i}),data_structure{i,2}.name))`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you. I figured out how to use fullfile and dir more appropriately, didn't get the last line.

Answer (score 2):

In the line

```
[y Fs] = audioread((data_structure{i,2}.name)); %%problem here
```

the expression `data_structure{i,2}.name` will feed the all the file names (47 in your example) at once as input arguments to the function `audioread`, hence the error message.

If you want to access each `.wav` file individually, you need to index them within the struct returned from `dir`, i.e.,

```
for i=1:num_sounds;
    these_files = data_structure{i,2};
    for i=1:length(these_files)
        [y Fs] = audioread(these_files(i).name));
        % Do whatever needs to be done with y, Fs
    end
end
```