# MATLAB - Specified all paths, but it's always opening to the last path?

Tags: matlab, struct, directory, logic, cell

`sound_dirs={Ball, Daddy,Jeep, No, Tea_Pot};`

The 5 variables in sound_dirs are path-char-vectors to 5 different sound folders.

- `data_structure` is a cell of (length(num_sounds) row x 3 column cell
- each row corresponds to a different sound
- first column = directory name
- second column = files struct for .wav files
- third column = formant data

I want to be able to index into the files struct and do some processing on each .wav file of the same type, and then generate statistics on the group.

**I use this method to get the '.wav' files**

```
for i=1:num_sounds;
     i_num_wavs=length(data_structure{i,2});
     ith_file=data_structure{i,2};
     for j=1:i_num_wavs;
     [y Fs]= audioread(ith_file(j).name);
% end x 2 at the end of the processing
```

### **The problem:**

The program I wrote always opens to the TeaPot Directory, which  is the last directory. So when I call the ith term in the for loop, I somehow get TeaPot files and those don't match up.

**I use this method to take off the last directory names to store in `data_structure{i,1}`**

```
for i=1:num_sounds;
    path=sound_dirs{i};
[path, fname, ext] = fileparts(path); 
opendir = strcat(fname, ext);
words{i}=opendir;
end
```

### **Where is the logic wrong?**

[image]

Comment: can't see where `data_structure{i,1}` is in the second code block. So does `ith_file(j).name` include the directory name or it is just the file name? if it is the file name, you need `fullfile(data_structure{i,1},ith_file(j).name)` to get the **absolute** path for the audio file.

Comment: @Anthony - `ith_file(j).name` only includes the `.wav` file. Thanks! I realized using `cd()` always gives the last directory.